# Making a command only run in certain cases in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to figure out how to get this command to only run in certain cases:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.js imap <buffer> {<cr> {<cr>}<c-o>O<Tab><Down>;<Up>
```

Examples:

```
// No!
if () {
}

// YES!
foo.x = function () {
};

// YES!
var x = {
  // NO!
  y: function () {
  }
};

// YES!
foo(function () {
});
```

So the pattern would be, NO semi IF it starts with `for|switch|if|else|if else` (and whatever else) OR if there is a `:` on the same line.

I really don't even know where to look.

Comment: you need to write a function and create a mapping to call it with
`au BufNewFile,BufRead *.js imap {<cr} <C-r>=MyFunction()`

You can also use a snippets plugin i like `https://github.com/drmingdrmer/xptemplate` or you could try `https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips`

Comment: It might also help use `inoremap` to prevent recursive mappings. I would suggest puting this in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim` that way you can make changes to the file and then resource it via `so ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim`. Keeps you from constantly reloading vim. May also help to look at Steve Losh's Learn Vimscript the Hard Way: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try `mapping with <expr>`.

I wrote a function, which returns the mapping you need with or without the semi. :

```
fun! Mapping()
    return "{\<cr>}\<c-o>O\<Tab>\<Down>".(getline('.') =~# '^\s*for\s\|if\s\|else\s'||getline('.') =~# ':'? '' : ';')."\<up>"
endfunction
```

then you could add this mapping into your `au`

```
inoremap <buffer> <expr> {<cr> Mapping()
```

note that I didn't put all the keywords in the line, I just added `if else for` as example. you could add other keywords and test.

Comment: I have this: `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.js inoremap <buffer> {<cr> SemiOrNoSemi()` and I copied and pasted your function above. However, doing just `function () {` actually outputs, literally, `function () SemiOrNoSemi()`?

Comment: expr？did u have that in ur mapping